# Difference between array initializers

Tags: c, arrays, cocoa, initialization, opengl-es-2.0

I am creating an array in `C` of known size that doesn't ever change. What is the difference between the following two initializers?

1.

```
GLuint boxArray[36];
for (GLuint i=0; i<36; i++) 
{
    boxArray[i] = i;
}
```

2.

```
GLuint boxArray[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35};
```

When I swap out the two methods above, only the first works in my code. Inspection of the arrays themselves look very similar (the only difference being the second method has zero values for two elements PAST the end of the array).

I am using the following code to inspect the array just after I create it...

```
for (int j=0; j<39; j++) {
    NSLog(@"boxArray[%d] = %d", j, boxArray[j]);
 }
```

Both outputs are the same with the above small difference.  I am purposefully writing past the end of the array to inspect differences there.

I am then stuffing the array into an NSData object that is an instance variable of the object that this code lives in.... like such...

```
_boxArrayData  = [NSData dataWithBytes:boxArray length:sizeof(boxArray)];
```

I can inspect the data on the other end when I pull the data out of the NSData object and it looks the same there as well.  However, when I use the data (it is a simple index array for OpenGLES2.0) I get different results.

Comment: This is just a guess but who knows: Replace `GLint` with `int` and see if the problem persists. Also, please post the code you use to print the array, chances are the problem is in there.

Comment: @rath: I agree with the second part, the error is probably with his printing code. int vs GLint should not matter though.

Comment: @Michael: Are you inspecting using a debugger of some sort? That could be the cause of these extra values you see. See if the code in my answer is equivalent for both initializations. It should be.

Comment: Your edited the code essential. Did this "solved" the problem? I think this is nonsense. Who wants to read the history of a question to get the initial question?!

Comment: Just to reiterate, you cannot go out of bounds. That is not handled by the language, and invokes undefined behavior. You are at this point testing the machine state, not the language.

Comment: Sorry for the initial typo...

Comment: @Segmented:  Thanks for pointing that out.  I have only gone out of bounds to debug a more persistent issue.  It might not be of any use, but I just find it odd that there are always two zeros past the end of the array.  I understand that this is not the point, but I am just trying to find out the difference between the two initializers...

Comment: @Michael: Either way, your question is now outside your original scope. You are no longer asking a C question. As for why they are different, that is due to your compiler no doubt. It is allowed to make assumptions based on you not going out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, the second initializer is treated as a 'constant' as far as the compiler is concerned.  So those values are being written to the constant block of the executable and pointed to directly by the array variable.

So the following zeros are likely another constant value somewhere in your code.  The compiler will line those two values up side by side in the executable as long as your code hasn't really changed.  Adding more constants may change this in the future.

If you look further past the memory block of your array, you'll likely see other constant values (including some recognizable strings)... assuming your code is substantial enough for that.

The first initializer obviously doesn't have this behavior, because the memory is instead allocated on the stack, and filled in later.  Since the stack can be allocated in different locations with each run of your program, the values after the top of the stack can be different every time.

So in summary, the second initializer makes your executable larger, but initiates MUCH faster since it's just pointing your variable to a constant.  The first initializer will make your executable smaller by the array size, but allocate the memory dynamically as you reach that portion of your code.  Plus using the loop to fill it in will be a ton slower than the second (comparatively).  Obviously a 36 element loop is super fast still, but a simple pointer assignment is much fewer cycles.

Comment: Thank you... very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

```
GLuint boxArray[36];
for (GLuint i=0; i<36; i++) 
{
    boxArray[i] = i;
}
```

Your assigning `boxIndeciesArray` not `boxArray`, or vise-versa since you said the first one worked.

EDIT: I see you have edited your question to fix this, can you elaborate more on how you are getting your values and exactly why it dosent work?

Comment: I thought declaring a variable inside a for loop is a no-no for C. Am I wrong in this? Plus, +1 for the catch, I totally missed it

Comment: I presumed he meant only in principal not literally but if that was literally the code he used then good catch, that would be the problem =)

Comment: @segmented Yea not sure if it was one of those "late night mistakes"

Comment: @rath, Im not a C programmer, I just thought this looked a little funny. With some quick googling, I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: @rath That's assignment, not declaration. Declaring a variable within an inner scope will make it inaccessible to the outer scope if that is what you are referring to, but that's not going on here.

Comment: I should have phrased it better: I though declaring a variable inside the *evaluation* of a control block was illigal in C (at least according to GCC). Eg. `for(int i=0; i<....);` would be fine in Java but C requires `int i=0; for(i=0; ...);` @Segmented

Comment: Oh I see, yea it depends on the standard you adhere to in that case. I think K&R C required you put int i; at the start of a block. I think C99 is more lax.

Comment: Sorry for the typo... all of the references to the array should have read boxArray, not boxIndeciesArray.  I have edited the question....

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you are getting your values and exactly why it dosent work?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining and initializing an array of size `36`. And then you print its contents as if it has size `39`. This, of course, runs out of bounds of the array and "prints" the non-existing elements past the end. The behavior is undefined. What you "see" beyond the bounds of the array (zeros or something else) does not matter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I am only reading past the end of the array to see what might be the difference.  The two initializers get different results if I remove the print outs completely;  I am using the array as an OpenGL index array.  They produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

They should be equivalent, the only reason I can think of why you would have values past the end of the array is because you are going out of bounds in the code you inspect the arrays with.

Inspect the array using code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, boxArray[i]);
```

You should see that they are indeed equivalent.

**Edit** You cannot go out of bounds, that invokes *undefined behavior* - anything can happen.

Comment: Thanks.  I have removed the read past the end of the array, and am inspecting the array only to element 36.  Everything runs the same.